# How to remove google place autocomplete close icon?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-google-places-autocomplete

I am trying to customize the close icon of google places search field, but I cannot seem to be able to remove the automatic close button. Has anyone been able to remove it?
I want to only use the icon specified in the renderRightButton property to reset the location.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import GooglePlacesAutocomplete from 'react-google-places-autocomplete';

const Component = () => (
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
        selectProps={{
          value,
          onChange: setValue,
        }}
       renderRightButton={() => <Icon name='remove' onPress=(() => resetLocation)/>}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: there doesn't seem to be an option, you would want to edit the library directly, I suggest you create a fork of the library and then make your changes in a new git branch via github then just use your own fork version instead. which has the changes you desire [official repo](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete) edit `GooglePlacesAutocomplete.js`

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen thanks for your response. What about possibility to edit the functionality of the current clear button?

Comment: you might want to use the reactnative dom, to hide the clear button using javascript

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen thanks again, with some digging I found the right property to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the right property to hide the clear button. If you add clearButtonMode: 'never' inside the textInputProps,it will remove the default clear button by google places autocomplete

```
   <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
    textInputProps={{
              clearButtonMode: 'never'
            }}
    selectProps={{
              value,
              onChange: setValue,
            }}
   renderRightButton={() => <Icon name='remove' onPress=(() => resetLocation())/>}
          />
```